# My zshell breaks because oh-my-zsh cannot update

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I reload my shell(on MacOS), I get the following error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOkyq.png)`[oh-my-zsh] Can't update: not a git repository.` When I try to delete pyenv or to do something else,I get the error that the command i not found. For example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq4Lg.png) What should I do to solve it?

Comment: You seem to have messed up your zsh startup files. I would trace the execution of a zsh startup (using `-x`) and in particular look for places, where `PATH` or `path` is modified, and things which are involving `git`.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated Xcode, try to run in your Terminal as Normal User:

```
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools && xcode-select --install
```

I don't know a permanent solution. This works till the next omz update...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the .zshrc file was broken and was adding wrong paths to the PATH variable. I deleted it and put the correct scripts.